# Idiomatic Usage of Haskell Foreign Types?

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

**Problem:** Going from Haskell types to Foreign types and back requires a lot of boilerplate code.

For example, suppose we're working with the following Haskell data structure:

```
data HS_DataStructure = HS_DataStructure {
       a1 :: String    
    ,  b1 :: String
    ,  c1 :: Int
}
```

In order to get this data structure into the land of C, we will need to consider its `struct` analogue:

```
typedef struct {
        char *a;
        char *b;
        int   c;
} c_struct;
```

But in order to pass such a struct into C from Haskell, we have to transform `HS_DataStructure` into the following:

```
data HS_Struct = HS_Struct { 
      a :: CString
    , b :: CString
    , c :: CInt
} deriving Show
```

We then have to make `HS_Struct` an instance of `Storable`:

```
instance Storable HS_Struct where
    sizeOf    _ = #{size c_struct}
    alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CString)

poke p c_struct = do
    #{poke c_struct, a} p $ a c_struct
    #{poke c_struct, b} p $ b c_struct
    #{poke c_struct, c} p $ c c_struct

peek p = return HS_Struct
          `ap` (#{peek c_struct, a} p)
          `ap` (#{peek c_struct, b} p)
          `ap` (#{peek c_struct, c} p)
```

(In the above I'm using hs2c syntax).

Now finally, in order to convert between `HS_Struct` and `HS_DataStructure`, we are forced to use the following helper functions(!):

```
makeStruct :: HS_DataStructure -> IO (HS_Struct)
makeStruct hsds = do str1 <- newCString (a1 hsds)
                             str2 <- newCString (b1 hsds)
                             jreturn (HS_Struct str1 str2 (c1 hsds))

makeDataStructure :: Ptr (HS_Struct) -> IO (HS_DataStructure)
makeDataStructure p = do hss <- peek p
                          hs1 <- peekCString (a hss)j
                          hs2 <- peekCString (b hss)
                         return (HS_DataStructure hs1 hs2 (c hss))
```

**This seems to be an insane amount of boilerplate to go back and forth between Haskell and C.**

#### Questions

1. Is there any way to minimize the boilerplate above?
2. With Haskell projects that involve a heavy amount of FFI, is it idiomatic to just give in and primarily use Haskell's C types (i.e., `CInt`, `CString`, and so forth)? This would at least save you the hastle having to convert back and forth between the types.

Comment: Given all of the FFI questions you've asked lately, I am getting really curious what you are building! That aside, there is probably a package that uses type families and template Haskell to do this. If there isn't, it shouldn't be too hard to do this.

Comment: @Alec: I am thinking about building a 3D window manager that pushes as much high level logic to Haskell, and as much performance critical code to C/C++.

Comment: Would [this package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/c-storable-deriving-0.1.3) work for you? It doesn't seem to support strings, but still.

Comment: @Alex: it's hard to for me to understand how that package works. Why doesnt it work on strings?

Comment: Note that C strings are tricky because they have to be allocated and freed manually. Your code never frees those strings it allocates, and AFAIK there's no automatic way to safely do that (in some cases, foreign pointers can do that when GC collects some Haskell memory).

Comment: @George Have you looked at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-c ?

Comment: @chi I think it's possible. A compiler can, after all, statically pick up lots of unused variables/logic, and thus should also be able to determine when an allocated chunk of memory can't be recalled anymore. The only times it seems it could be questionable are in undisputably poor software development practices, such as writing pointers to a network and then expecting them to be echoed back.

Comment: You can try [c2hsc](https://github.com/jwiegley/c2hsc)

Answer (score 1):

"Idiomatically", I think there is no way getting around the boilerplate for marshaling values between C and Haskell. However, there are answers to your question that you might find useful. After having written and contributed to [a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netcode-io) [number](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reliable-io) [of](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yoga) [libraries](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-GLFW) that wrap C libraries for Haskell users, I would highly recommend using the [bindings-dsl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-DSL) library to address your problems, which uses [hsc2hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsc2hs) under the hood. Specifically, to answer your questions:

**1. Is there any way to minimize the boilerplate above?**

You can eliminate some of it, but marshaling between C types and Haskell types in most cases requires care to make sure that Haskell values remain well founded. This is a feature, not a bug, since C types are inherently different representations. For `String` and `CString`, for example, you need to specify what happens if you call

```
makeStruct $ HS_DataStructure (repeat 'a') (repeat 'b') 0
```

... or how to handle memory allocation (your example will leak without a corresponding `deleteStruct` function). Similarly there are concerns about integer semantics with `Int` and `CInt`. What happens if you get a `CInt` that's out of range of `Int`? Clamp? Wrap? These answers are usually application-specific, and the interoperability with other libraries requires that the invariants hold for all Haskell programs.

Using [bindings-dsl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-DSL), we can at least get rid of the need for writing your own `Storable` instances by defining a `.hsc` file with the following:

```
module MyModule where

#include <c_struct.h>

#starttype struct HS_Struct
#field a, CString
#field b, CString
#field c, CInt
#stoptype
```

If you add this module to your cabal file, cabal should recognize that it needs to use `hsc2hs` and will compile it properly adding all of the additional instances. Look at any of the links above for examples. Your code for `makeDataStructure` can be made (a bit) simpler, too:

```
makeDataStructure :: Ptr HS_Struct -> IO HS_DataStructure
makeDataStructure p = do
    HS_Struct ca cb cc <- peek p
    HS_DataStructure <$> peekCString ca <*> peekCString cb <*> fromIntegral cc
```

The real "boilerplate reduction" win from using `bindings-DSL` comes from the [Haskell-side FFI definitions](https://github.com/jwiegley/bindings-dsl/wiki/FunctionsAndMacros) of functions that exist in the headers.

**2. With Haskell projects that involve a heavy amount of FFI, is it idiomatic to just give in and primarily use Haskell's C types (i.e., CInt, CString, and so forth)? This would at least save you the hassle having to convert back and forth between the types.**

Having something be "idiomatic" is a bit subjective (and hence susceptible to both bikeshedding and gatekeeping), so any answer you get to this question you should take with a grain of salt, and might not be the best fit for this site. In my opinion, I don't think primarily using C types is idiomatic. Those types exist for the sole purpose of interfacing with C, and the Haskell runtime is optimized around Haskell types. If you find yourself writing so much FFI that you feel the need to primarily use FFI types, that might be a good indication that you should be writing a C library instead.

The exception is, of course, if you're writing a Haskell library that's wrapping a C library. In this case, I'd argue that the whole point of the Haskell library is to implement the boilerplate in a way that is consistent between the Haskell runtime and the C library interface.

---